# Informix password expiring soon exception

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I access an Informix (IDS 11.50.FC7) database from a Java application. For connection purpose I use functional user for which password expires every 180 days (due to internal policy).
Unfortunately I don't know the exact date when the password will expire but I'd like to know it in advance. I don't have root priviledges on my unix server where the database is installed so I can't use any of "password tools" and can't look into /etc/shadow file also.
The only idea is to use jdbc connection for testing it... 
Is there any exception of incoming password expiration ("Your password will expire in xx days")? If so how can I catch it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exception for that.  The password is still valid, so Informix reports success when you connect, and continues to do that until the password expires.  There isn't a way to get a 'success with extra information' status.

Since there is no exception, there's no way to catch it.

Doesn't your internal policy notify functional users when their password is scheduled to expire?  It probably should.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advice. I work in very distributed corporation but I will try to seek smb who could notify me of password expiration.